# Need support for Automated Workflow (Google Forms to Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to using Google Apps Script/ coding in general and I'm encountering a few issues with my workflow automation. I hope someone here can help me out.

**My Project:** I'm working on a project where I want to automate the process of taking data submitted through a Google Form and using it to create a personalized Google Sheets document for the User. This Google Sheet should also have an autofilter applied to show specific data. I'm using the onFormSubmit trigger to kick off the script when a form is submitted.

**The Code:**

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var currentSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()); 
    var dataRange = currentSheet.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("name of file where data is pulled").next();
    var masterFile=folder.getFilesByName("Master file").next();
    var masterSS = SpreadsheetApp.open(masterFile);

    // Duplicate the master template 
    var newSS;
    try {
        newSS = masterSS.copy(masterSS.getName() + ' for ' + e.values[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        Logger.log(error.toString());
        return; 
    }

    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    var targetSheet = newSS.getSheetByName('Formularantworten 2');
    if (targetSheet) {
        targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); 
    }

    function setAutoFilter(newSS) {
        var sheet = newSS.getSheetByName("Leitfragen");
        var range = sheet.getRange("C9:C" + sheet.getLastRow());

        if(!sheet.getFilter()) {
            sheet.setDataRange(range);
            sheet.createFilter(); 
        }

        var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setHiddenValues(["gering/nicht betroffen"])
        .build();
        sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(3, criteria);
    }

    newSS.getSheetByName("Formularantworten 2").hideSheet();
    currentSheet.deleteRows(2, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1);

    var form = FormApp.openById('XYXXYX');
    var confirmationMessage = 'Here is your personalized climate adaptation guide! ' + newSS.getUrl();
    form.setConfirmationMessage(confirmationMessage); 
}
```

**My Problems:**

1. **Using the Latest Form Data**: The script doesn't seem to wait for the latest form submission to arrive. Instead, it sometimes takes data from the previous entry. I need it to work with the most recent data submitted.
2. **Applying Autofilter:** I'm trying to apply an autofilter to the newly created Google Sheet to show specific values, but it doesn't seem to be working.
3. **Waiting for 5 Seconds:** I've attempted to use "Utilities.sleep(5000)" to pause the script for 5 seconds before continuing, but it doesn't pause at the right point in the script. This step is meant to ensure that there's a delay, giving sufficient time for the new data from the form to fully populate the linked Google Sheet before the script proceeds to copy the data.

I also tried the following at the beginning of the script:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties(); 
var lastTimestamp = userProperties.getProperty('lastTimestamp'); 
var currentTimestamp = e.values[0];

if (lastTimestamp === currentTimestamp) {
    var start = new Date().getTime(); 
    while (currentTimestamp === lastTimestamp) {
        if (new Date().getTime() - start > 60000) {
            break; 
        }
        currentTimestamp = userProperties.getProperty('lastTimestamp');
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
}

userProperties.setProperty('lastTimestamp', currentTimestamp);
```

This didn't work.

I'm open to any help or suggestions on how to address these issues. Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner when it comes to coding, so any assistance or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The data that is associated with the current form submission is inside of the submit triggers event object.  That is what e.values is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the sheet linked to the form that is generating the on form submit trigger then this is the simplest way to go:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
}
```

and if you wish to know the row on that sheet where the data that is linked to the current submission is, then `e.range.rowStart` is the answer.

I think you need to back up a little and learn some of the basics before diving into automating the process for others.  You might wish to learn them yourself first.

Comment: My problem is mainly that i just don´t get the current data into the generated sheets. It always takes the ones from the former submission. 

For better understanding User B submits the Forms - gets a link to the sheets that was created for User A before. User C gets the link for User B and so on. 
It doesn´t take the current data. 
I have tried loops, where it should take upto 10 seconds to make sure it takes the right data.

I have tried to do it via time stamps. Nothing worked.
I always get the link instantly in the moment the Forms is submitted with the data from the last entry.

Comment: Is there some way to force that loop process? I know that it doesn´t properly do it because the Url gets provided instantly after the submission. I have also tried it with

`SpreadsheetApp.flush();
Utilities.Sleep.sleep(5000);
SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

or also 

`Utilities.sleep()` 

by it self

Comment: Don't take the data from the sheet take it instead the from event object of an onformsubmit trigger

Comment: The other option might be to use SpreadsheetApp.flush just before accessing the sheet.